# Support TinyMCE in Korean

Tags: tinymce, cjk

I'm using open source **TinyMCE**. Does TinyMCE editor support displaying the panel in Korean? And what I have to do use in korean on my site

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Korean is supported according to the list here:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/localization/#language

1. Download the Korean language pack from [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/language-packages/).
2. Unpack the language file into your tinymce/langs folder.
3. Set the language option in your TinyMCE configuration to the language code `"ko_KR"`.
4. Confirm that the language has been set successfully by loading TinyMCE.